# How to run script only when user land on page

Tags: javascript, html

I have some script, written in Javascript, that show progress of loading site elements. I put this script on index.html file, so it runs only on main page. It works perfectly fine, but now it show progress when you land on index.html and also when you come back to main page from subpage which is my problem because main page is already cached and it's waste of time.

My question is:   How to run script only when user land on page, not when he come back from subpage?

Comment: onload in body/form will do..

Comment: Cookies won't work all the time because their persistence is not correlated with the cache.  How does your progress indicator work? Is it shown for a fixed amount of time?

Comment: It depends on how many things have to be loaded. When main page is cached and I come back from subpage it just show up and immiedatly disappears. But still this isn't what I expected. I think that Wayne's idea with document.referrer solved problem easily.

Comment: If you had to go with one or the other, I'd go with cookies over **referrer** due to it failing in the case where you leave the site and come back. Using them together will marginally help (when losing cookies while navigating your site).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to cookies you can use document.referrer:

```
<script>
if(document.referrer &&
document.referrer.indexOf("yoursite.com") == -1)
{
    // Page loading process script goes here.
}
</script>
```

Comment: It seems that this solved my problem, but it works properly without first document.refferer condition. Did I missed something?

Comment: First document.referrer is to test if there is a document referral. Some times "rarely" it is blocked and does not exist. Without it the loading process will be shown to these people, and is only prevented from being shown to people who are "known" to come from a sub page.

Comment: I am going to guess you typed in the URL so the browser had no value for the referrer - It was blank.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with it ... I keep the pair together because this same logic works to break out of frames. Then it is necessary to check that a document referrer exists.

Comment: But when I keep it your way (with first document.referrer), it just doesn't work - script is never executed and my progress indicator never show up. Your idea (but without first document.referrer) solved my problem, but I'm still curious why this isn't working form me, when I keep it your way.

Comment: When you type in the url there is no referral so the first test is false. The && is a logical condition that means both of these must be true to be true (or 1). If one of them is false (or -1) then they logically "&&" to false (-1).

Answer (score 4):

Try [cookies](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html) to control when/when not to execute Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Create a cookie when the user hits index.html for the first time.  Check for the cookie and only run the script if the cookie hasn't been set.

```
if(!isset($_COOKIE['something'])) {
    // run your loading script;
    setcookie('something','someValue');
}
```

Just be sure you have the above code before sending any output to the browser.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
..
</head>
<body onload="doStuff()">
...
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">
//<![CDATA[
 function doStuff(){
   //check condition
   if (readCookie('checkFirstTime')!=null) return;

   //otherwise set the flag && do your thing
   createCookie('checkFirstTime','yep',1);
   alert("Welcome home Yo!");
   ...
 }

function createCookie(name,value,days) {
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
    }
    else var expires = "";
    document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/";
}

function readCookie(name) {
    var nameEQ = name + "=";
    var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
    for(var i=0;i < ca.length;i++) {
        var c = ca[i];
        while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1,c.length);
        if (c.indexOf(nameEQ) == 0) return c.substring(nameEQ.length,c.length);
    }
    return null;
}

//]]>
</script>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Elaborating on what I told JMC Creative: isset(), $_COOKIE[], and setcookie() are not built-in javascript properties/functions.

Comment: Just thought a general explanation was required not a detailed couple of functions for managing cookies. Anyway, I've edited the answer. Hope it helps